# Spring boot + camel + rabbitmq - how to gracefully exit and requeue to another queue

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I am encountering a very strange issue (at least for me!) when I am doing some rabbitmq processing with camel. Here is the approximation of my route DSL

```
onException(IOException.class)
    .bean("killApplication with Spring.exit")
    .handled(true);


onException(JsonPathException.class)
    .removeHeaders("*")
    .to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/<bad messages queue>")
    .handled(true);


from("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/<central exchange>")
    .filter().method("some bean filtration")
    .removeHeaders("*")
    .to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/<local queue>");
    .end();
```

All is well until I get the IOException and do a SpringApplication.exit but control does not come back to my terminal. It just blinks and I need to do a Ctrl^C to exit from the application.

Upon some investigation the culprit was the .to in the JSONPathException. If I comment the line

```
//.to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/<bad messages queue>")
```

all is ok and the application exits with control back to terminal prompt.

I am stumped. I do not want to use the dlq of rabbit but I want to push to my own queue upon a badly formatted message.

Can someone please tell me what could be causing this problem? I only find answers via rabbit dlq to this issue but like I said I want to route to my own queue upon an exception (and on another exception I would like to kill the app). Needless to add a system.exit kills the application but I do not want to do that as I want a graceful shutdown.

Please note that the intriguing part is that the JSONPathException is not even the activated route. It is an IOException that triggers the kill, so it is even more confounding that a path not even in the trigger path is causing the issue.

Comment: I think the issue is you are rmoving all headers before posting to rabbit. I am guessing you need to set some headers based on your rabbitmq queue/exchange setup and hence rabbit is returning an error. Check your exchange details and set the headers accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean wrt exchange/set up. Can you give me an example for I have not set any headers etc. I also tried the following to no avail:
onException(JsonPathException.class)

    .removeHeaders("rabbitmq.*")

    .setHeader("rabbitmq.DELIVERY_MODE", constant(2))

    .to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/<bad messages queue>")

    .handled(true);

Comment: Your rabbitmq exchange. How is that configured compared to your Camel code? You need to make sure if the exchange is a topic then it should say so in your header as well.

Comment: It is a topic. I only have one central exchange. In my camel the route is
.to("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/central-exchange?autoDelete=false&exchangeType=topic&skipQueueDeclare=true&routingKey=temp.dlq")
The routing key of temp.dlq is supposed to send it my custom dlq queue. 
Also please see my EDIT to the question

Comment: You need to examine more your connection to Rabbit. Why don't you first start by just sending something or just receiving and then add more logic? Get one thing to work. I suspect your connectivity to Rabbit is not correct.

Comment: My happy path goes fine. I am able to consume a message, do some validation and move it to another queue for further processing.
After testing this scenario is when I started with the negative scenarios of exception. So using camel to read rabbit mq works fine. The only thing I am not able to understand is that the JSONPathException is not even invoked (when I thrown an IOException), so why is that path even triggering?